# pdflatex can't find an installed package

Tags: packages, texlive, wrapfig, linuxfedora

I installed texlive on Fedora. I'm trying to move from Overleaf to (Doom) Emacs + AucTeX, and so I downloaded one of my already written files from Overleaf and tried to run it through pdflatex. However, I keep getting,

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'wrapfig.sty' not found.
```

presumably since I declared `\usepackage{wrapfig}` in my LaTeX file. This isn't the first package of the document, and hence I know that packages like amsmath could be found.

After looking at some other questions that had similar problems, I have tried the following:

`tlmgr search --file "wrapfig.sty"` gives me that

```
lwarp: 
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-wrapfig.sty
wrapfig:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
```

and `kpsewhich wrapfig.sty` gives me nothing, while running `tlmgr show --only-installed wrapfig` gives me

```
package:     wrapfig
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Produces figures which text can flow around
longdesc:    Allows figures or tables to have text wrapped around them. Does not work in combination with list environments, but can be used in a parbox or minipage, and in twocolumn format. Supports the float package.
installed:   Yes
revision:    61719
sizes:       doc: 349k, run: 29k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 3.6
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  text-flow
cat-related: wrapfig2
collection:  collection-latexextra
```

I have also run `sudo mktexlsr` and `sudo texhash`, which does not solve the problem. So my understanding is that texlive installed wrapfig, but pdflatex cannot find it. Same thing happens with the package epigraph. I don't think this should be a Doom or AucTeX problem, but as a (very) beginner it could be the case.

Thank y'all!

(This is my first time asking a question on StackExchange - please let me know if something is wrong with the way I asked the question!)

Comment: My understanding is that it's `kpsewhich` that actually matters.  What's the output of a package that does work, like `kpsewhich amsmath.sty`?

Comment: Then I get `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty`, which is indeed different from how `kpsewhich wrapfig.sty` would work. Does that mean wrapfig wasn't a part of texlive?

Comment: wrapfig is a part of texlive.  It should be located at `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty`.  Do you have that file?  If not, how much of that path do you have?  And how did you install texlive?  Did you use the package manager, or did you install texlive following https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html?  And did you choose a minimal installation, or a full installation?

Comment: Since I'm on Fedora, I installed using `sudo dnf install texlive`. It wasn't texlive-full or any such extensions. It seems that I have up till 'latex' but I don't have the directory 'wrapfig'. 
Do you recommend that I do a different installation of texlive?

Comment: Unless your system is severely constrained in terms of hard disk space, I can see no downside to installing the “full” version of TeXlive. If nothing else, you won’t ever again have to spend time inquiring on this forum why a given LaTeX package might be “missing”.

Comment: Sanity check: what does `which tlmgr` give you? Fedora's packaging of TL is, frankly, a mess. Try `dnf search texlive-full` and see if there's a package or meta package by that name. If so, install that. Otherwise try `dnf search texlive` and look through the results for something useful. Installing from upstream is an option, but it has its own pitfalls. In particular, you need to install dummy packages to keep `dnf` happy when you install texlive-dependent software (e.g. editor etc.). Just don't install both!

Comment: do not use tlmgr for the system installed version of texlive that you are using, use your normal linux package manager dnf or yum or apt or ... whatever your flavour of linux uses

Comment: @Mico I definitely might, thank you. I am confused as to why `tlmgr` seems to be suggesting all these packages are installed, but I guess installations maintained by the distro just doesn't talk too well with that command. 
@cfr `tlmgr` gives me /usr/bin/tlmgr. I think I'm going to try the more extensive texlive maintained by dnf, and then if that doesn't work, I'll have to follow TUG instructions (after removing the existing texlive). 
@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fedora and other Red Hat-derived distributions, you can search for packages that provide a particular file with "dnf provides */wrapfig.sty" at the command line.

In this particular case, the package is called "texlive-wrapfig"; typing "dnf install texlive-wrapfig" (either as root or using sudo) will install it.

In this case, you may already have the file but something in your ls-R isn't what it's supposed to be. Try "dnf reinstall texlive-wrapfig" or perhaps even "dnf reinstall texlive" and see whether that helps.

Comment: Thank you! So instead of installing wrapfig through `tlmgr` (at this point, I'm not sure what that command is supposed to be...) I'll install it through `dnf`.

Comment: @kohdy I don't think any of the Linux dists provide a LaTeX installation where you can install packages using `tlmgr`. You need to install the upstream TeXLIve in order to use `tlmgr`. The Linux dies does not like users installing stuff using tools outside of their packing system.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you, I've learned a lot about how TeX distributions are handled :)